# Debugging with Tomcat and Intellij Community Edition

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I started Tomcat as instructed here: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing using this command

> catalina jpda start

I set up Intellij as depicted below

[image]

It connects to the debugger successfully

but when I click next to every single line I get a red x as shown below. I know for a fact the line contains executable code. Either way every line says the same thing.

[image]

**What could I be doing wrong or differently?**

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm running into a similar issue and have exhausted all possible solutions I could come up with.

Comment: I did resolve it, you must make sure that the source is compiled with debugging symbols included.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure you include debugging symbols in your compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when the changes made require a server restart. It is possible that the  server was not able to pick up the new changes without restarting & earlier the line did not have any executable code.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle, you can try my script: https://github.com/Adrninistrator/IDEA-IC-Tomcat .This script will build files for web application, create a Tomcat instance, start Tomcat and load the web application.
I wrote how to debug Tomcat with IDEA Community Edition in the README.md.