# How can I do remote debugging with my tomcat server running on an VM in IntelliJ community Edition?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to remote debug an application. My tomcat server is running in a Vm. I am trying to connect to it to debug. How can I connect to it?
NOTE: I am trying to do this in windows machines.

Already tried the solution mentioned in.

[How to debug a Tomcat 7.x/8.x webapp locally with IntelliJ Community (free) version in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655978/how-to-debug-a-tomcat-7-x-8-x-webapp-locally-with-intellij-community-free-vers#). But after following the steps, I am getting:

```
Error running 'Local Apache Tomcat': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:12000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
Error running 'Local Apache Tomcat': Unable to open debugger port (10.194.43.79:12000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

Made sure the jdk that I am mentioning in settings. And the one which is installed in vm machine, It's same.

I am able to ping the machine.

I've tried to connect to it with tomcat which is running on my machine. It's not working.

Acc. to [How to debug a Tomcat 7.x/8.x webapp locally with IntelliJ Community (free) version in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655978/how-to-debug-a-tomcat-7-x-8-x-webapp-locally-with-intellij-community-free-vers#)

I should've received:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '10.194.43.79:12000', transport: 'socket'
```

Instead it's:

```
Error running 'Local Apache Tomcat': Unable to open debugger port (10.194.43.37:12000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"
```

Comment: Is your port you are trying to connect is same as you have provided in your JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: Yes. CATALINA_OPTS  = "$CATALINA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=12000" 

I went catalina opts and have triedn JAVA OPTS as well.

Comment: when I put his : set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=12000" 


in catalina.bat file in my local machine. Then I am able to connect.


 Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:12000', transport: 'socket'


But not able to do this with my VM.